# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Suspended

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow that is supposed to send an email to a set of addresses stored in the document metadata when "request action" is selected. It never seems to get passed the first stage and goes into suspended almost immediately. Here is the error code.

```
RequestorId: f8c18955-9af8-ac75-0000-000000000000. 

Details: RequestorId: f8c18955-9af8-ac75-0000-000000000000. 

Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. 

Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. 

Parameter name: Input at 

Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at 
System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at 
System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the following powershel cmdlet after you are publishing the workflow

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yourportal
$list = $web.Lists["yourlist"] //This is the list that is associated with your workflow.
foreach ($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations) {Write-Host $wf.name ":" $wf.Id} //This will help you identify the id for your workflow.
foreach ($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations) {if($wf.Id -eq "Insert ID of workflow here"){$mywf=$wf}} //This will get the workflow we want to add the association data for.
Write-Host $mywf.Name //Confirm you have the correct workflow
$mywf.AssociationData = "<AssociationData><Dummy></Dummy></AssociationData>" //Set our association data
$list.WorkflowAssociations.Remove("Insert ID of workflow here") //Warning, test this in a dev environment first. This may take a little while depending on how many active workflow instances you have.
$list.WorkflowAssociations.Add($mywf) //You'll get a printout after showing the workflow information
$web.Dispose()
```

You can also check this [article](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/an-unhandled-exception-occurred/) that it is related to your issue.